# Filtar por Título profesional

Tags: php5

Hola Gente realice un buscador de apellidos en donde me lista los profesionales con sus datos y titulo.
El problema me surge que el cliente no quiere que en ese listado se vean los TÉCNICOS.
Busque por todos lados pensando que el filtro lo podía hacer en la consulta sql, pero no conseguí ningun resultado. Lo estoy haciendo con if, else, pero tengo unas 40 o mas opciones de TECNICOS en la base. Hay alguna forma de simplificar esta tarea? Adjunto el código.

```
$query= "
SELECT * 
FROM 
base_old
WHERE
apellido LIKE '".$apellido."%'";
$sqlf = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlf)) {
$dni = $row["DNI"];
$nombre = $row["nombres"];
$titulo = $row["TIT"];
$titulo1 = $row["TIT2"];
$apellido1 = $row["apellido"];
$estu = $row["TipoMatricula"];
if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD EN EL TRABAJO"){
echo"
<div></div>";
} else if($titulo=="TECNICO EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD LABORAL") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO SUPERIOR EN HIGIENE, SEGURIDAD Y CONTROL AMBIENTAL") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO SUPERIOR EN SEGURIDAD E HIGIENE EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO SUPERIOR EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD LABORAL") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO SUPERIOR EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TÉCNICO SUPERIOR EN SEGURIDAD E HIGIENE EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TÉCNICO SUPERIOR EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN SEGURIDAD E HIGIENE EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN SEGURIDAD DE HIGIENE DE LA INDUSTRIA MECANICO 
AUTOMOTRIZ") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD LABORAL") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN HIGIENE Y SEGURIDAD EN EL TRABAJO") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else if($titulo=="TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO EN GESTION AMBIENTAL") {
echo"
<div></div>";
}
else{
echo"   
<div class=\"noticias b mb-3\">
<div class=\"row\">
<div class=\"col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3\">\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querés traer todos los profesionales menos los técnicos? Podrías editar tu consulta para que no traiga los profesionales cuyo título empieza con la palabra "técnico".

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM base_old WHERE apellido LIKE '" . $apellido . "%'" AND titulo NOT LIKE 'TECNICO%';
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo más eficiente es desde la consulta, donde veo que está devolviendo todo con * ,

```
SELECT DNI, nombres, TIT2, apellido, TipoMatricula
```

y eso es todo, no tiene porqué devolver el titulo esa consulta.

Comment: Si en realidad debe devolver ese valor en la consulta, entonces sencillamente en el frontend, aplique una clase a la etiqueta donde se imprimen los técnicos , y posteriormente con CSS hacer , display:none